# Unity doesnt shows correctly after proprietary nvidia even after linux-headers-generic

Tags: unity, nvidia

I just reinstalled ubuntu 12.10 and cant get nvidia proprietary drivers to work properly in the unity dash..  Previously before formating i installed the linux-headers-generic tweak and it worked, but now even if i install it it stays messy!! Someone help!

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```